# SQL INSERT INTO select

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert

Currently using a MySQL database

Wanting to insert a new row into a `table (t_2)` for every matching entry in my where condition of another `table (t_1)`.

I also want to include a count value from a seperate table for each entry (count from table counter) and a string value 'decrease' for each entry.  No idea how to put this through, this is what I have so far:

```
INSERT INTO t_2(count,id,val='decrease')
SELECT MAX(count) as count FROM counter
SELECT id FROM t_1 WHERE val < 0
```

the error I am getting is:

> > 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your  MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '='decrease') SELECT count FROM counter SELECT id FROM t_1 WHERE val < 0' at line 1

I know I probably shouldn't have the `val='decrease'` but just wanted to illustrate I want that to be a string value inserted for each new row.

Comment: Was just about to ask the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO t_2 (count,id,val) 
SELECT 
    (SELECT MAX(count) FROM counter),
    t_1.id, 
    'decrease'
FROM t_1 
WHERE val < 0,
```

Comment: If i wanted to add a field to the string value, can I just concatenate it like normal?  For example:
`('decrease ' + t_1.detail) as val`

Comment: @elzaer: you should use [CONCAT('decrease ', t_1.detail)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
INSERT INTO t_2(count,id,val)
    SELECT (SELECT MAX(count) as count FROM counter) as count, id, 'decrease' as val
    FROM t_1
    WHERE val < 0
```